# Prestashop multistore and multilingual URL rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop

Setting up a Prestashop with multistore functionality together with multilingual support. This means that Prestashop from default would define my URL as:

```
domain.com/store/lang => domain.com/uk/ja   (UK store with Japanese language)
```

However I would really appreciate my URLs to have both store and language at one level:

```
domain.com/store-lang => domain.com/uk-ja
```

I figured out that this might be possible through either .htaccess or the dispatch.php file.
However can't seem to get it working. And I would also appreciate a solution where it is not too hacky and harcoded many places.

I hope someone might have tried this before or maybe able to think of any possible solution :)

## No correct answer

We have not come up with any solution to this issue. I am going to implement the application with /store/language and hope it wont affect the user or SEO. I have chosen to accept the answer below even though it is not actually working. However it was the only answer and really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a rewrite rule

look http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/content/6-prestashopseotips (and http://www.webshopstarter.com/shoppingcarts/prestashop-seo-friendly-urls/)

and add:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(.*) $1/$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. So what you are saying is that it would actually be a better solution to keep /store/language? And not go with /store-language? For example Apple => store.apple.com/hk-zh and store.apple.com/hk same country store, but different language. I don't think ?language is preferred by Google. And I would not put extra levels into the URL, like /store/uk/ja, just /uk/ja then.

Comment: if you have only `GET` (?sth=1) you can use `QSA`. That will send the data also. `RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+) $1/$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I have edited my question with the current .htaccess file. The links you are referring too are a bit old, and Prestashop will actually generate the htaccess automatically now. Anyway I tried to put in your RewriteRule but cannot seem where it should be and how it would work. You know that I want URL from: /uk/en to become /uk-en right? Thank you very much.

Comment: try to add RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8888$ RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(.*) $1/$2 [QSA,L,R=301] just after RewriteEngine on, manually, then try to browse `http://localhost:8888/uk-en` then of course it's better to put it pretashop config (you should post it, along with the generated .htaccess)

Comment: That does not work. I get redirected back to /uk/en/ however now it goes directly into page-not-found (Prestashop 404).

Comment: Actually it looks like you have misunderstood what I want. Your setup would probably work, however it redirects me back to /uk/en and my point was to have the URL to be /uk-en/ - and keep it like that.

Comment: when you put a rewriteRule ^(\w+)-(.*) $1/$2 if you type localhost/foo-bar in your browser, it keeps like that, but the server will fetch the resource located at localhost/foo/bar, if it doesn't work then you probably have another rule, can you try with this one only if possible

Comment: Thank you. I figured out what is redirecting the code, stripping the .htaccess down to nothing but your suggestion. The rewrite rule seem to work fine /foo-bar becomes /foo/bar, however I still can't get this to work. It looks like Prestashop catches the request into their Dispatch.php class calling dispatch(). Link to the code here: http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/prestashop-e-commerce-solution/prestashop/classes/Dispatcher.php - in here Prestashop thinks that my request is still /foo-bar/. Updated my question with updated .htaccess file.

Comment: yes it's passed to dispatcher, the best thing is to make this url conversion work with dispatcher rules, or else maybe try `RewriteBase /pretashop/`  `RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(.*) $1/$2`

Comment: Sorry it didn't work either. I still get caught in the Dispatcher.. Annoying but it seems to be a bit more difficult to change such a thing. It is apparently really deeply integrated on the slashes.

Comment: you need to post your dispatcher rules (what generates the htaccess)

Comment: The dispatcher does not exactly create anything in the .htaccess and even if it did, what would it help? We have already tried to edit the .htaccess. However the whole content of the Dispatch.php class is in my previous comment (a link). More specific it is in the dispatch function. What do you think?

Comment: I have accepted your answer even though it is not working. See my last edit of my question :) thank you.